# IAP non-consumable item gives extra points after first purchase

Tags: ios, xcode, storekit, in-app-purchase

I have one non-consumable IAP called "Pro Version". I give buyers some extra points and some access.

There is no problem when they buy it for the first time. It gives the points and removes the restrictions.

But when they try to buy it again it says "you have already purchased this item tap ok to download it again" and then it gets to SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased and gives the points again.

I tried to put a keychain so it will give only once for a device but if someone takes another device and logs in with their account which they bought the game, they will get the points again.

Any ideas to solve this ? I mean should I change the place where they take points( It gives the points after validateReceiptForTransaction is successfull ) ?

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the in-App Purchase guidelines (https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf), you must provide a restoring methode for your non-consumable IAP .

So, for your problem :

> if someone takes another device and logs in with their account which
>   they bought the game

make a restoration when a user attempts to log in.

You would be able to know if the user have bought or not your IAP.

I think you have to check if a user have made the purchase and then allow or not him to purchase your non-consumable.